# How to access a function defined in a previous YUI.use() call

Tags: yui3

[I'm a YUI newbie]

I'm writing a Chrome extension that needs to change the contents of a web page created using  the YUI3 framework.

I've identified that the extension, which injects javascript that runs in the page after it is loaded, must call a function that was previously defined in a YUI.add() call.

The original YUI code that runs is something like this:

```
YUI.add("uuu", function (c) {
    ...
    c.theObject = niceStuff;
}
...
YUI().use("uuu", function (c) {
    c.theObject.doSomething();
}
```

**Is it possible that after this code runs, I can access a function of c.theObject?**

(I understand this might go against YUI3's nice sandbox mechanism, but it's what I need to get the job done here).

Comment: Works for me. Can you post more code?

Comment: Yes, his example works, but what he was trying to do is access c.theObject after that example ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have problems because any time a YUI() instance is created, it builds you a new sandbox. With a few exceptions, YUI modules are completely boxed by their sandbox context. For example:

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y1) {
    YUI().use('node', function(Y2) {
        assert(Y1.Node === Y2.Node) // fails!
    });
});
```

It's very possible that you may not be able to access the *specific instance* of `theObject` that you need, if it's never assigned to a variable outside the sandbox function scope. If any instance of theObject will do, you can just call into the YUI API and get your own version to play with.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sMAQx/1/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to capture the YUI() instance after you 'use' it.  Like this:

```
YUI().add("uuu", function (c) {
    c.theObject = 'foo';
})

var yInstance = YUI().use("uuu", function (c) {
    c.theObject = 'booyaa';
})

yInstance.use('uuu',function(c){
console.log(c.theObject)
})
    // booyaa
```